# What's the difference between different approaches to demonstrating closedness (etc.) sets?

Tags: general-topology

What's the difference between different approaches to demonstrating closedness (etc.) sets?

What confuses me that sometimes I for example find showing

complement is open $\implies$ the set is closed

easier than some

"take a sequence of elements and show that limit is not in the set"

---

The problem with this latter approach is that I find that depending on the set it could be difficult to construct such sequence.

---

Or would you say that these are equivalent in terms of "difficulty"?

Comment: It's hard to know how to answer your question. Mathematical methods apply differently to different mathematical problems. "Closedness" might be demonstrated one way in one problem and a different way in a different problem. Learning the correct way to demonstrate it in a particular problem is part of the job of the mathematician. If you have a question about doing this in a particular problem that's one thing, but as the question is currently posed I don't think it is answerable.

Comment: Put a *concrete* example where "could be difficult to construct such sequence".

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla $\{ n : n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ is closed, but other than noticing that its complement is union of open intervals $(n,n+1)$, then how would one prove that some sequence would not have a limit in this set? I guess one could show that the sequence difference cannot be less than one?

Comment: Right. Using that the space is discrete is the essential fact.

Comment: That "take a sequence of elements" stuff does not always hold.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I rememberd that these were equivalent definitions? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set It's just that some cases might be syntactically more labourous through some other path than another. Same like in integration some integrals can become "impossible" using another approach, while they might be simpler when done through integration by parts or other trickery.

Comment: Consider @mavavilj the space [0, $\omega_1$] and the open subset A =  [0, $\omega_1$).  Every converging sequence from A converges in A.  Sequences are only useful for 1st countable spaces.  In general to use this clumsy method, nets are needed.